# Why is the onSharedPreferenceChanged method of this Settings Activity blank?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, live-wallpaper

I created a live wallpaper for android.  I'm trying to implement a settings menu and I've having a great deal of difficulty.  Basically, everything works except the settings from the settings menu are not being picked up by the `Wallpaper service`.  I'm using `SharedPreferences`based upon this tutorial:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper?fid=1586900&df=90&mpp=25&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Normal&spc=Relaxed&fr=51#xx0xx

I'm trying to figure out why the settings are not being carried over to the main `Wallpaper Service`, and it occurred to me that the the `onSharedPreferencesChanged` method of my `Settings Activity`, which extends `PreferenceActivity` is blank.  I don't have my code with me at the moment, but this code is very similar, so my question is why is the `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method blank and should it be?  It seems to me that this is where the code should be that actually makes the changes.

Here's the code:

```
package ca.jvsh.livewallpaper;

import ca.jvsh.livewallpaper.R;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class LiveWallpaperSettings extends PreferenceActivity
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(LiveWallpaper.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.livewallpaper_settings);
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void **onSharedPreferenceChanged**(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
            String key)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to be blank. This method is called so you can perform any specific changes you may want to do. But the value of the Preference has already changed. Just check if you are checking the value of the preference correctly.

Comment: Where is the Preference being changed?  The `onCreate` method only appears to register the listener, but I don't see where it actually changing the value of the Preference.  It seems to me that that should occur in the `onSharedPrefernceChanged` method.

Comment: Android does that for you. It's not visible in your PreferenceActivity

Comment: Thanks...  I guess I'll just have to take your word for it...  I suppose my issues are elsewhere in my code.